# Script to generate a list of urls from a list of authors

Tags: xargs

I need to take a list of authors names of which may consist from 1 to 4 words like this

```
Osho
Hartmann Nicolai
Bird Robert Montgomery
Coates Ta-Nehisi
```

and generate URLs like this

```
site.com/word1+word+word3+word4
```

If I do it like this

```
< list.txt xargs -l | xargs printf '"site.com/%s\n' > url.txt
```

it will accept one word. My question is how do I add 3 more optional parameters like `%s`? Or maybe there are easier ways with other commands?

Comment: its ok, nevermind)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest awk for text processing tasks like this:

```
$ awk -v site="site.com" -vOFS=+ '{$1=$1; print site "/" $0}' list.txt
site.com/Osho
site.com/Hartmann+Nicolai
site.com/Bird+Robert+Montgomery
site.com/Coates+Ta-Nehisi
```

Answer (score 2):

After testing your command, I got this result :

```
"site.com/Osho
"site.com/Hartmann
"site.com/Nicolai
"site.com/Bird
"site.com/Robert
"site.com/Montgomery
"site.com/Coates
"site.com/Ta-Nehisi
```

As I can see, you want to replace each space with a `+`, so you can use the `sed` command like that :

```
< list.txt xargs -l | sed "s/\ /+/g" | xargs printf 'site.com/%s\n' > url.txt
```

Here is the result :

```
site.com/Osho
site.com/Hartmann+Nicolai
site.com/Bird+Robert+Montgomery
site.com/Coates+Ta-Nehisi
```

This command is really effective and dynamic, you can have a really long composed name (with 6, 10 or more parts), only space would disappear, each `-` character won't even be modify

NB : I just removed the `"` character inside your `printf` command because it's not need in your expected output

Comment: i am getting some concatenation site.com/Atwood+Margaret+Ayer+A+J+Backman+Fredrik+Bailey+Derek
site.com/Banks+Russell
site.com/Barker+Nicola
site.com/Barker+Susan+Barnes+Djuna
like the first one is composed of 3 authors

Comment: ok, i have the solution thank you

Comment: @Коля Please tick the best answer as **Accepted** instead of saying *thank you* in comment, it would help further readers

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `sed`, three times:

- The first sed removes the leading an trailing spaces
- The second one replaces the remaining spaces with `+` chars
- The third one prefixes the result with `site.com/`

So the expression could be

```
cat input.txt | sed -e "s/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//" | sed -e "s/\s+/+/g"  | sed -e "s/\(.*\)/site.com\\/\1/"
```

The output is

```
site.com/Osho
site.com/Hartmann+Nicolai
site.com/Bird+Robert+Montgomery
site.com/Coates+Ta-Nehisi
```

Comment: site.com/Battersby+Eileen
site.com/Batuman+Elif
site.com/Baudrillard+Jean
site.com/Bayle+Pierre
site.com/Beagle+Peter+S++
site.com/Beatty+Paul
site.com/Beaumont+Francis
site.com/Bede
site.com/Begley+Sharon
site.com/Beiser+Frederick+C+

it works but there is some surplus of "+" signs))

Comment: ok, i have the solution thank you

Comment: I improved my solution to remove leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bash
input="/path/to/list.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "http://site.com/${$line// /+}" > urls.txt
done < "$input"
```